# Bazel and Tensorflow Error on Raspberry Pi: Building From Source

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, raspberry-pi, bazel

I am trying to run a command to install Tensorflow from source, I use Bazel to install from source (This is being done a raspberry pi -- Linux OS software).

This what I am trying to do on my raspberry pi (I am trying to model the instruction from here: https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md):

```
./configure

bazel build -c opt --copt="-mfpu=neon-vfpv4" --copt="-funsafe-math-optimizations" --copt="-ftree-vectorize" --copt="-fomit-frame-pointer" --local_resources 1024,1.0,1.0 --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I am using Bazel version 0.10.0

I get the following error when I run it (This is a super long installation and it was almost done installing all the files and then it suddenly said the build failed, and Bazel couldn't be built. Does anyone know how to fix or have resources on how to fix this error)?

Here is the error message that I get:

```
/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/BUILD:391:1: Linking 
of rule '//tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco' failed (Exit 1): gcc 
failed: error executing command 
(cd/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/c9b23b7b8edb3dba430c02139630698d/execroot/org_tensorflow && \


 exec env - \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64 \



PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin \

PWD=/proc/self/cwd \

PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python \
```

> PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages \
>
> TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=0 \
>
> TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
>
> TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 \

I have searched the web for hours but have not come across anything that looks remotely similar to the error I am facing. Guidance, help or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have copied is not thecreal error message. It should be logged much earlier.

Comment: @KlausD. I have edited my posts to include the errors. It seems to be a problem with CUDA, but I said that I do not want CUDA in my ./configure. Do you know why this error would be occurring? Let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: Can you show output for `gcc --version` command

Comment: @DinushaDilanka   gcc (Raspbian 4.8.5-4) 4.8.5

Comment: Try  to install via pip as `pip install tensorflow`

Comment: @DinushaDilanka For which command? Like which command, I already have Tensorflow installed.